# ASPX page access external resource strange behavior

Tags: asp.net, globalization, resx, hebrew

I have a ASP.NET web site project that needs to access resources that reside in an external assembly. To do so I have created based on some samples an expression builder class in my web site code

```
Public Class GlobalizationStringExpressionBuilder
    Inherits ExpressionBuilder
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Overrides Function GetCodeExpression(ByVal entry As BoundPropertyEntry, ByVal parsedData As Object, ByVal context As ExpressionBuilderContext) As CodeExpression
        Return New CodePropertyReferenceExpression(New CodeTypeReferenceExpression(GetType(Trackem.Globalization.My.Resources.Resources)), entry.Expression.Trim)
    End Function
End Class
```

Trackem.Globalization.My.Resources.Resources is the name of the external resource assembly

in the web config I have added

```
<expressionBuilders>
    <add
        expressionPrefix="GlobalizationString"
        type="GlobalizationStringExpressionBuilder" />
</expressionBuilders>
```

and in each control I have put

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ GlobalizationString:LABEL_FIRSTNAME %>" Mode="Encode"></asp:Literal>
```

I am also overriding the InitializeCulture page event and setting the thread properties

```
    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        Dim up As UserPreferences = UserPreferences()
        Dim lcid As Int32 = If(up IsNot Nothing AndAlso up.UILanguage <> 0, up.UILanguage, 1033) 'default to English if no setting found
        Dim ci As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lcid)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci

        MyBase.InitializeCulture()
    End Sub
```

This all works well on a lot of production servers and each user can see the site in his own preferred language.

On a few Windows 2008R2 machines, every few days something happens (not sure what) and somehow the resource managers get confused serving Hebrew resources although the page should be in English (I have put response.write of the current thread culture and the page is convinced it is in engligh 1033 but the resources being output are in Hebrew). When this happens a simple IIS pool recycle solves the problem

Am I missing something? As I said I am not sure what triggers this but a simple pool recycle and everything is back to normal for a few days